# Java program to accept 6 inputs in an array and find the highest of all. And if any of the numbers are negative the loop has to be terminated

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So in this code I had created a code to read 6 values and print the highest of the 6 numbers. That worked well but now if one of the numbers are negative, I want the loop to stop there and exit printing Invalid Loop. But in my code the program prints the highest mark after printing Invalid Input. How do I avoid this?

This is on IntelliJ platform Java v5.0

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Highestmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a[] = new int[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();                  // To exit loop
            if (a[i] < 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Mark");
                break;
            }
        }
        int max = a[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {        // To find highest
            if (max < a[i]) {
                max = a[i];
            }
            System.out.println("Highest Mark is" + max);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
25
-26
Invalid Input
```

But the actual output is

```
25
26
27
-28
Invalid Input
Highest Mark is 27
```

Comment: I expect the output to be 25 -26 Invalid Input. do you mean only -26

Comment: @SSP OP meant that's what is expected in the console. The 25 is the first input, then the second input, -26, is rejected.

Comment: I want the program to terminate whenever I enter a negative number. But the problem here is that the program does break when there is a negative number but it still prints the highest mark after that.

Comment: If you want to terminate use `return` instead of `break`.

Comment: break is used to terminate the loop. Statements after loop are executing in their sequence. That's why it always print your highest mark. Use return instead to avoid this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break` only breaks the for-loop but then continues with the code below. You probably just say `return` instead or `System.exit(0);`

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified a bit, no need to keep an array:

```
public class HighestMark {

  private static final int MAX_INPUT = 6; // could just hard-code this in loop, but good practice to set constants

  private static final Scanner SCAN = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int highest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_INPUT; i++) {
      int next = SCAN.nextInt();
      if (next < 0) { // validate the input (require non-negative int)
        System.out.println("appropriate error message...");
        break;
      }
      if (next > highest) {
        highest = next;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Highest mark is " + highest);
  }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a boolean flag.

Set the flag to false, when there is any negative number.

Check the flag before checking max number.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a[] = new int[6];
boolean flag = true;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = sc.nextInt(); // To exit loop
    if (a[i] < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Mark");
        flag = false;
        break;//return; //System.exit(0); any of these 3 will work fine.
    }
}
if (flag) {
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) // To find highest
    {
        if (max < a[i])
            max = a[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Highest Mark is" + max);
}
```

Comment: Nah, just return or exit

Comment: Why down vote ? and no reason. exit in 1 way to do it. flag is another way. and we should avoid exit method as there can be more code to run.

Comment: Also change to `for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)`

Comment: Thank you :) I replaced break with return and it succeeded!

Comment: *I want the loop to stop there and exit*

Comment: already updated my answer. just missed that exit line in question. my bad.

Comment: I'd rather use a flag and keep my code extendable for future changes. OP might want to prompt some kind of retry dialog after inserting invalid numbers. I don't see any need for this nitpicking optimization.

Comment: @JuliusHörger You want to keep your code extendable for future changes, but still want to pack all the code into one method? You only need a boolean flag when you already screwed up a proper code structure, so "future changes" are certainly not one of the concerns when writing such code.